# Beginner Python: Display objects in list within GUI window using tkinter

Tags: python, list, object, tkinter

I want to use tkinter to display lists I am making in a simple window. However, I am unsure of the proper way to format this.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import simpledialog
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

class Survey:
    def __init__(self, width, length):
        self.length = length
        self.width = width
    def setLength(self, length):
        self.length = length
    def setWidth(self, width):
        self.width = width
    def calArea(self):
        return self.length * self.width
    def describe(self):
        return (f"length:",self.length, "width:", self.width, "area:", self.calArea())

areaList = []

lot1 = Survey(32.3, 35.0)
areaList.append(lot1)

lot2 = Survey(52.6, 46.1)
areaList.append(lot2)

lot3 = Survey(39.8, 57.2)
areaList.append(lot3)

window = Tk()
window.title("Survey Results")
window.geometry('300x300')
for x in range(0, len(areaList)):
    text = Label(window, areaList[x])
text.grid(column=0, row=0)
```

Currently I am experiencing this error that I think needs me to change the list to a string, but I'm not sure how to do that here.

> TypeError: argument of type 'Survey' is not iterable

My window opens, but it is empty. I tried `text = Label(window, str(areaList[x]))` further errors put me in over my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

object of class is nor iterable.
use the code below:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import simpledialog

class Survey:
    def __init__(self, width, length):
        self.length = length
        self.width = width
    def calArea(self):
        return self.length * self.width
    def describe(self):
        return (f"length:",self.length, "width:", self.width, "area:", self.calArea())

areaList = []

lot1 = Survey(32.3, 35.0)
areaList.append(lot1.describe())

lot2 = Survey(52.6, 46.1)
areaList.append(lot2.describe())

lot3 = Survey(39.8, 57.2)
areaList.append(lot3.describe())

window = Tk()
window.title("Survey Results")
window.geometry('300x300')
for x in range(0, len(areaList)):
    text = Label(window, text=areaList[x])
    text.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

you are putting the instance of Survey inside a list and trying to take it out as a string without telling it what part you want out (aka the describe() function)

```py
for x in range(0, len(areaList)):
    text = Label(window, text=areaList[x].describe())
    text.grid(column=0, row=0) ## this should be the same indentation
```

A better method of doing this skipping all the bad code habbits:

```py
for sv in areaList: ##loops through the actual items in the list rather than the index:
    Label(window, text=sv.describe()).grid(column=0, row=0) ## this can be 1 line if you dont need to do anything with the widget after.
```

Also you missed `window.mainloop()` at the end of the code. not sure if thats just a copy/paste error or its actually missing